# JScrollPane doesn't show scroll bars when JPanel is added

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I'm tried to add a JPanel to a JScrollPane using:

```
    panel1 Panel1 = new panel1(); 
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Panel1);
```

and it worked. But the problem is scrollPane doesn't show scroll bars even the Panel1 is bigger. (I'm working with NetBeans & panel1 is a jpanel form)

Answer (score 5):

Override, [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize--) method for the said `JScrollPane`, you might be able to see the Scroll Bar. Or one can simply call [setPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize-java.awt.Dimension-), though as stated in the API

> Sets the preferred size of this component. If preferredSize is null, the UI will be asked for the preferred size

overriding will be beneficial, as it tends to define some appropriate dimensions to the said `JComponent`.

Something like this:

```
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 200);
    }
};
scroller.setViewportView(panelWithScroll);
```

One example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelScroller {

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Worker Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelWithScroll = new JPanel();
        panelWithScroll.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 200);
            }
        };
        scroller.setViewportView(panelWithScroll);
        //scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            panelWithScroll.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(i + 1), JLabel.CENTER));
        }

        contentPane.add(scroller);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PanelScroller().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both, calling setPrefferedSize() and overriding getPrefferedSize() but that didn't worked. Then I tried changing the layout of my Panel to a GridLayout and that worked.(Also works for AbsoluteLayout & FreeDesign) Thanks for ur help.

Comment: I am not sure about what the default(I guess GroupLayout, with which I am not familiar with, since never worked on any IDEs before) `LayoutManager` is used by __NetBeans__, that might be causing the issues, since the example posted above, clearly demonstrates what I am referring too.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the scrollbars to show up you can call

```
JScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
JScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

But that don't make them work at all.

if you wont to make them work you can try to set the preferred size of the component inside the Scrollpane to larger then size of Scrollpane and then call repaint(e.g. by make the window fullscreen)