# JScrollPane not showing content until mouse scroll or frame resizing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane with a JPanel in it that works perfectly, except for one flaw. When I run the program, the JScrollPane is added and shows up on its parent panel just fine, however the content inside it does not show up.

If I resize the window or if I scroll on the JPanel the content shows up immediately. I have also checked and the dimensions are correct for both the JPanel and the JScrollPane. Repaint is also called so I don't think I'm missing anything there.

I did also look at this question but it didn't help:
[JScrollPane doesn't show scroll bars when JPanel is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639132/jscrollpane-doesnt-show-scroll-bars-when-jpanel-is-added)

Null layouts being used are intentionally, I'm doing my own formatting instead to account for multiple size screens. Thank you ahead of time!

```
class FilesPanel extends JPanel
{
    public JScrollPane scroller;
    private FileHolderPanel holder;

    public FilesPanel()
    {
        //setLayout(null);
        setBackground(extraLight);

        holder = new FileHolderPanel();

        System.out.println(holder.getWidth() + " " + holder.getHeight() + " " + holder.getX() + " " + holder.getY() + " " + holder.getBounds());

        scroller = new JScrollPane();

        JViewport viewport = new JViewport();
        viewport.add(holder);
        scroller.setViewport(viewport);

        scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        scroller.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        scroller.setBackground(blue);
        add(scroller);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        scroller.setLocation(0, 0);
        scroller.setSize(filesWidth, frame.getHeight() - 40);
    }

    class FileHolderPanel extends JPanel
    {
        public FileHolderPanel()
        {
            setBackground(extraLight);
            setLayout(null);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the code out of `paintComponent`, this is NOT how custom painting should be used, nor is it a good idea.  The "main" problem, as near as I can tell is failure of the `FileHolderPanel` to provide appropriate sizing hints for the `JScrollPane` to use

Comment: `viewport.add(holder);` is also not required

Comment: Doing your own layout is much more involved than what you are doing. Layouts really do make things easier.

Comment: Added the full code folder here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vIPJ93s70AT_P6V3zNLmAB7XgSHGE2T2?usp=sharing
The class is called FilePanel

Comment: Hi Brad Kyle. On Stack Overflow, you are expected to include a [MCVE] to your question. You cannot expect people to go look for resources elsewhere to solve your question. Not just that, Stack Overflow is a repository of questions and answers that are supposed to help anyone facing a similar problem. Once you remove the code from your Google drive, your question would become useless.

Answer (score 2):

The "main" issue is the fact that `FileHolderPanel` has not concept of the size it might like to be, so the `JScrollPane` has no really of how large it needs to be or when it should display its scroll bars.  This is a bit of guess work, as you've not provided a fully runnable example.

Something like the below example works fine...

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new ContentPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ContentPane extends JPanel {

        public ContentPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new FileHolderPane());
            scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            scrollPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            add(scrollPane);
        }

    }

    public class FileHolderPane extends JPanel {

        public FileHolderPane() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("All your content is belong to us"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            // This will make the panel a fixed size, so beware of that
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

    }
}
```

If you need more control, then you'll probably need to look at the `Scrollable` `interface`, but that's another level of complexity

Comment: Unfortuantely, I tried this and got the same result. If you're still willing to help, I uploaded everything so you can look att eh full code, but I didn't want to post the whole thing here as it is quite long. The class is called FilePanel. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vIPJ93s70AT_P6V3zNLmAB7XgSHGE2T2?usp=sharing

Comment: @BradKyle You say you tried it, but perhaps you should run MadProgrammer's example and see if it shows the same problem as you face. I doubt it though, this is very standard code for scroll panes. Then work up to what you want from MP's code.